# Can a githzerai PC be a psionicist in AD&D 2e?

Tags: psionics, class, adnd-2e, planescape, gith

The complete psionics handbook was released before Planescape campaign setting and there is no mention of githzerai being able to be psionicist. But from the lore it seems that they can be psionic.

- Can a githzerai PC have a psionicist class?
- What should be the level limit for them?
- Is there any (even homebrew) source for that?

Answer (score 5):

### Not by the rules, but the DM can allow it

Rules as written, Githzerai characters cannot be psionicists, even if they have a natural bend towards psionics. The *Planescape Campaign Setting* states (p. 12):

> Character classes **are limited to** fighter (9th-level maximum), fighter/wizard (9th/12th levels respectively), wizard (12th level), or thief (15thlevel maximum). The githzerai revere an ancient wizard-king as their god, and they have no priests

How serious the book is about these limititations can be questioned. On p. 90 we encounter Yangol, an NPC character that is a Githzerai (Mage/Thief)-(W2/T3), something not possible according to the strictures above.

*The Planeswalkers Handbook* further advises (p. 90):

> Prime characters are naturally allowed the full range of class options found on their prime-material worlds. **Planar characters are usually limited to the classes found in the Player's Handbook**, unless a player presents a compelling argument to the DM to allow otherwise.

and Gith, although decended from humans in the eons of time, count as planar, with their home plane in Limbo. So, they would not be able to become Psionicists based on this, either. This takes us to the "compelling argument" for the DM.

#### Allowing it anyways

Githyanki and Githzerai are really the same orginal race, Gith, they just train their mental capacities in different ways and have different philosophical outlooks. p. 124 of *The Complete Psionics Handbook* lists Gith as a monster race option that has access to Psionic powers

| Level | Dis/Sci/Dev | Attack/Defense | Power Score | PSPs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| =HD | per level | All/All | Int | 1d100+150 |

I think this natural penchant for psionics is a good argument why, with Gith as a player race, they should be among those races that can become psionicists.
Further more there is this comment, from the *Planeswalker's Handbook* (p.91)

> OTHER CLASSES. **Psionicists are basically wizards**, as far as
> most planewalkers are concerned - although their highly
> trained minds are certainly worthy of respect in a place
> where the power of minds and beliefs can change the multiverse

Now, this is of course from an in-character perspective and more tongue-in-cheek, they are not *really* wizards. But, as Githzerai can be Wizards, and from the viewpoint of most in the multiverse that a Psionicist is really just another flavor of Wizard, then the DM could grant that a Psionicist should be fine, too.

Comment: I've also found this passage in the "Player Options - Skills & Powers"
"All races eligible for use as player characters can become psionicists. Human psionicists have no limit on the
levels of experience // All creatures not listed here
can reach 10th level. "
Thank you for your help, because with your explanation I can at least see why I won't break a game by allowing player to make this character

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative to Nobody's answer if you consider The Player's Options books. In "Player's Options: Skills & Powers" the githzerai is available as character race and in psionicist class description we find:
"All races eligible for use as player characters can become psionicists. Human psionicists have no limit on the levels of experience they can attain in their chosen class. Half-elves, half-orcs, and half-ogres (due to their partial human heritage) can reach 12th level. Halflings and gnomes can attain 10th level. Dwarves and elves can reach only 8th level as psionicists. All creatures not listed here can reach 10th level."
So a githzerai could reach max level 10 as psionicist.